# if list contains variable change it to item once

Tags: python, if-statement, replace

```py
d = input("fill in:")
d = d.lower()
y = ['a', 'b', 'c']
if d in y:
  for x in y:
    d = d.replace(x, "d")
    print(d)
else:
  print("false")
```

If the user fills in a, b, or c it is supposed to print out d, if not a,b,c it is supposed to say "false". In this case the program returns 3 times, how do I fix this?

Comment: If it's supposed to print out "d", why don't you simply do that instead of that entire `for` loop?

Comment: You've put the `print('d')` statement inside the loop which runs for 3 times, that's why it is printed three times. try moving the print statement out of the loop, or rather just avoid the loop and directly work with `if`.

Comment: Your request is kind of odd but delete the for loop, write `d = d.replace(d, "d")` and keep your `print(d)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  for x in y:
    d = d.replace(x, "d")
    print(d)
```

You *specifically* told the program to print (not "return") three times.
If you don't want three lines printed, then move the `print` statement outside of the loop.